# 12.04 not recognizing data on USB

Tags: 12.04, usb

I recently got the Sims 3, and copied the ISO to my computer which runs windows 7. I then moved the ISO to my laptop, which runs Ubuntu 12.04, and it would mount the ISO, but it would appear to be empty. I then tried to open the ISO in the Archive Manager, and it gave me this error:

```
CD-ROM is NOT in ISO 9660 format
```

So, instead of trying to mess with it, I went back to my desktop, thinking it was just Ubuntu not supporting this ISO. So I extracted the files from the ISO, then moved them to my USB drive.

When I plugged my USB drive back into my laptop, Ubuntu read the USB, but only says that there are two folders on the USB, and no other files, such as the rest of the files I had put on there. It still says that there is 6 GB used by the USB drive, but there is nothing there.

Why is it doing this? Could it be something with the formatting of the programs?
How could I fix this?

EDIT 1: I think I found a solution, and am testing now.

Edit 2: Did not work, still not showing certain files. I can open the ISO in Archive Manager, but when I try to extract the files, it only shows two folders, just like last time.

Answer (score 0):

Use Synaptic Package Manager to install a package called `iat`.  If you don't have Synaptic installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once installed, open synaptic and search for `iat`, and install it. You can use it in terminal to convert between ISO 9660 format.

For more info see [iat ManPage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/iat.1.html)